# Android GMail APIs is throwing 403 Forbidden Error when Application is SIGNED with release certificate

Tags: android, android-studio, gmail-api, google-signin

I have an Android custom MailApplication in which Gmail accounts can be added through Gmail APIs(with Google Sign-In). I have created a Project in Google Console server "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library".

I have enabled all the required APIs for accessing GMail and provided my debug key SHA1 along with my application package name. So far, Everything is working fine.

However, When I generated Signed certificate and get respective SHA1 and added it to Google Console Project in the Google Server and I have signed my Application with the created certificate, My GMail APIs stopped working and throwing 403-Forbidden error.

Can some one please point out whether I am missing something.
Why this is working only with debug certificate but not with signed certificate.

Below are my scopes details.

private static final String[] SCOPES = {GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS, GmailScopes
            .MAIL_GOOGLE_COM, GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY, GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY};

I have configured my release certificate properly in my AndroidStudio-2.2.1 as per the documentation below.
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Signing the Certificate step is "Build-> Generate Signed APK..."

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you try clearing your cache first? This was suggested in [this forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en&visit_id=1-636155567612734690-3399201708&rd=1#!topic/gmail/UkGDuzzSk_s;context-place=topicsearchin/gmail/403$20error)

Comment: @noogui, This suggest wnt be helpful because signed APK will be installed after the debug Application is uninstalled properly. and Even in while building the Application, I am doing clean build before signing the Application.